# Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My friend and I are disagreeing on this answer... Turning here for someone to correct one of us haha. We get different answers.

> Solve:
>   $$y' = -\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$$ where $y\left(\frac 1 4\right) = \frac 1 4$.
>
> Find $y\left(\dfrac 1 9\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're really only worried about $x,y>0$, then we may as well rewrite this as $$y'=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}.$$ This then can be rewritten as $$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}=-\frac1{\sqrt{x}},$$ so $$2\sqrt{x}+C=\int-\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\int\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}\,dx=\int\frac1{\sqrt{y}}\,dy=-2\sqrt{y}.$$ Using our initial value $y(1/4)=1/4$, we find that $C=-2$, so $$2\sqrt{x}-2=-2\sqrt{y},$$ so $$\sqrt{x}-1=-\sqrt{y},$$ and so $$y=\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)^2.$$ From this, we see that $y(1/9)=4/9$.

Answer (score 2):

After integrating you get, $2y^{1/2} = -2x^{1/2} + C $

Since $y(1/4) = 1/4, C = 2;$

Hence $y(1/9) = 4/9$